# How to center align a pattern?

Tags: c++, console, formatting, output, ascii-art

How can I align this arrow tail centered unded the arrow head?

```
    **
   ****
  ******
 ********
**********
****
****
****
****
```

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int n;
  cout<<"enter size";
  cin>>n;

  int rows,columns;
  cout<<"enter numbers";
  cin>>rows>>columns;

  for(int k=1;k<=n;k++){
    for(int j=1;j<=n-k;j++){
      cout<<" ";
    }
    for(int j=1;j<=k;j++){
      cout<<"*";
    }
    for(int i=1;i<=k;i++){
      cout<<"*";
    }
    cout<<endl;
  }
  for(int i=1;i<=rows;i++){
    for(int j=1;j<=columns;j++){
      cout<<"*";
    }
    cout<<endl;
  } 
  return 0;
}
```

I try to run it with the following input:

```
enter size 5
enter numbers 4 4
```

The arrow looks fine, but the tail is left aligned.  How can I get it into the center?

Comment: Print the appropriate number of spaces?

Comment: down below what I meant.

Comment: That’s exactly what I said, is it not?

Comment: I've removed the picture and extracted the relevant information in the body of the question.  This allows people to easily reproduce your problem.  Use screenshots only in last resort, as it tends to upset readers here.  Btw, I took the opportunity to pretty-print your code using usual alignment conventions.  This facilitates reading and tracking of structural issues (i.e. what is in what nested loop).  I hope you don't mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you display fixed spaced characters on a terminal, the general algorithm is:

- Take the width `we` of the element you want to center.
- Take the width `WA` of the area it needs to be centered in
- Print `(WA-we)/2` whitespaces before the element

Considering that in your case `WA` would be  `2*n` and `we` would be columns,  you could write somewhere:

```
 int s=(2*n-columns)/2;
```

and print in the second part of your algorithm `s` spaces before starting printing the `*` of your Christmas tree trunk.

By the way, I don't know if you're allowed to use string for your homework,  but if yes, you could replace the loops for printing `w` characters `c` one after another with just printing `string(w, c)`, (for example `cout<<string(s, ' ');`), which will make your programme more compact and readable.